# # Adding a row to a matrix that is the sum of multiple subsets of other rows in the same column

Tags: r, matrix

I want to add a SINGLE new row to my matrix where each column of the new row is the sum of rows 1 through 3 and rows 5 and 6 in each column.

I've been experimenting with rbind and rowCols to try to find the answer:

```
     # example
     mat <- matrix(1:21, byrow = TRUE, nrow =7)
     matplus <- rbind(mat, colSums(mat[1:3, ])) # works fine, but
```

I want to create an 8th row where each column is the sum of (a) rows 1-3 AND (b) rows 5 and 6;  like this:

```
     obj <- rbind(mat, c(41,46,51))


    >       [,1] [,2] [,3]
    >[1,]    1    2    3
    >[2,]    4    5    6
    >[3,]    7    8    9
    >[4,]   10   11   12
    >[5,]   13   14   15
    >[6,]   16   17   18
    >[7,]   19   20   21
    >[8,]   41   46   51
```

(But of course, I need to be able to calculate 41, 46, and 51)

Various attempts....

try #1

```
    matpplus <- rbind(mat, c(colSums(mat[1:3, ]), colSums(mat[5:6, ])))
```

This doesn't work with this warning:

> In rbind(mat, c(colSums(mat[1:3, ]), colSums(mat[5:6, ]))) :
>   number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

try #2

```
      matpplus <- rbind(mat, colSums(mat[1:3, ]), colSums(mat[5:6, ]))
```

Adds two additional rows rather than one

try #3

```
      matplus <- rbind(mat, colSums(mat[1:3, ], mat[5:6, ]))
```

Same results as try #1

Perhaps someone else has asked this simple question, but I cannot seem to find it; there seem to be plenty more complex questions, but none this basic.

Appreciate any help....

Comment: You're almost there with the `colSums`, I think you need to select both `1:3` and `5:6` at the same time: `rbind(matplus, colSums(matplus[c(1:3, 5:6), ]))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, you're almost there with the colSums, you can select both 1:3 and 5:6 at the same time and then do the `colSums`:

```
rbind(mat, colSums(mat[c(1:3, 5:6), ]))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#[3,]    7    8    9
#[4,]   10   11   12
#[5,]   13   14   15
#[6,]   16   17   18
#[7,]   19   20   21
#[8,]   41   46   51
```

The issue you were running into with `rbind(mat, colSums(mat[1:3, ]), colSums(mat[5:6, ]))` was that you were trying to stack 2 rows onto `mat`. One that is the `colSums` of rows `1:3` and another that is the `colSums` of rows `5:6`

Comment: Thanks @Mike H..  I can't believe I didn't think to try that variation.  It's in my notes folder for future use.